# Is it better to create lots of Gtk widgets instead of passing context in methods?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm very new to GTK/GTK++ and I come from MFC, so I know I have a couple of bad habits to get rid of ;)

I'd like to know what's the best way (as in "most efficient") to draw UI blocks in a `Gtk::DrawingArea`. These blocks can be drawn at any location in the drawing area (I can't use a stack or a table).

Right now I've created a class `UIBlock` and added a `Draw()` method in it. So, in my derived version of `Gtk::DrawingArea::on_draw()`, I call all the `UIBlock::Draw()` and transfer to them the `Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>` and a `Glib::RefPtr<Pango::Layout>` I created for drawing the texts.

So I have something like that:

```
// MyDrawingArea.h
class MyDrawingArea : public Gtk::DrawingArea
{
protected:
    virtual bool on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> const& cr) override;

private:
    std::vector<UIBlock> m_uiBlockList;
}

// MyDrawingArea.cpp
bool MyDrawingArea::on_draw(Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> const& cr)
{
    for(UIBlock const* uiBlock : m_uiBlockList)
    {
        uiBlock->Draw(cr, layout); // I've got a few other parameters like a bunch
                                   // of layouts for the different fonts I use,
                                   // the UI block position, etc...
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this solution is good or if it'd be easier and more efficient to simply derived my `UIBlock` class from a `Gtk::Widget`.

Hope I was clear about my question ;)
Thanks!

**Edit:**
As I said in the comments of drahnr's answer, GooCanvas is not an option, because it's [not developed anymore](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/goocanvas-list/2014-July/msg00001.html). The next-gen canvas API is Clutter, but it's integration in GTK is [still being worked on](http://www.bassi.io/articles/2014/07/29/guadec-2014-gsk/).

So I'll keep using my home-made Cairo solution for now. But I still need to know if there are good practices to display a lot of rectangles and texts on a canvas. Here is a [screenshot](https://plus.google.com/photos/+RomainFailliot/albums/5994060420563947665/5994061265644646130?pid=5994061265644646130&oid=111931671734626727541) of what I've got now, but when I have several hundreds of thousands of rectangle, it's a bit slow...

Comment: GooCanvas does receive (somewhat irregular) updates, was adapted to GObject Introspection and is still working very nicely

Answer (score 1):

You are reimplementing `GooCanvas` (unless you have further constraints you did not mention) - it has a `GooCanvasItem` which can hold regular `GtkWidget`s (called `GooCanvasWidget`).

https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GooCanvas?action=show&redirect=GooCanvas

Comment: Could be a solution, but I don't see exactly the difference between `DrawingArea` and `GooCanvas`. Could you explain briefly?

Comment: `GooCanvas` provides Objects that are part of your canvas which can receive individual drag, clicked, move events and already creates a drawing tree, but still provides the ability for custom drawing and boudningbox checks. It already does the dirty work, not to mention interactive positional modifcation of `GtkWidget`s (i.e. gravity for widgets to name one dumb example). With your approach you'd get a image but you'd not get anything interactive without coding event handling (correct me if I am wrong or I misunderstood what you actually try to achieve).

Comment: You're right, it seems to answer most of my issues. I'm just concerned about the performances, I might have thousands of widgets drawn in the window. Don't know if the GooCanvas could handle that. But it's a path I'll definitely test one day! (once my 1.0 version of my app is ready)

Comment: You can still use one widget adding it to multiple containers (actually never tried, but it *should* work). `GooCanvas` comes with plenty examples, have a look at them. At least for simple items 30k are not really an issue, see `scalability-demo`.

Comment: Also adding more detail on what exactly you want to do with the Canvas would help to give further advice.

Comment: I'm doing a profiler. That's why I need to display a lot of blocks. But if GooCanvas can handle 30k items, it's seems like a really good solution!

Comment: If you want to see what I'm doing I've put the code on [github](https://github.com/MightyCreak/libbench). It's in the "tool" directory.

Comment: @Creak will have a look sometime this week, probably friday

Comment: From what I gathered, GooCanvas is [not developed anymore](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/goocanvas-list/2014-July/msg00001.html) and the next-gen canvas is Clutter, but it appears to be more of a work in progress when it's about integrating it in GTK, based on [Clutter's developer itself](http://www.bassi.io/articles/2014/07/29/guadec-2014-gsk/).
So I'll keep on doing my own system and try to find what's the best way of doing it.

Comment: If you want an idea of what I want to display, here is a screenshot: https://plus.google.com/photos/+RomainFailliot/albums/5994060420563947665/5994061265644646130?pid=5994061265644646130&oid=111931671734626727541